# Hide a view and adjacent gap with autolayout

Tags: ios, cocoa, user-interface, interface-builder, autolayout

I have the following configuration of a view:

[image: Autolayout with hiding image]

Sometimes I have an image to put in the image view, sometimes I do not. If there is no image to show, I would like the Title label to be extended to the right, occupying the whole space of the image and the gap between the label and the image. I assigned a constraint "less than or equal" to the width of the image view, so I guess it might get zero width if the image property of the image view is null. But how do I remove the gap between the image view and the title label? I know it is possible from code by defining an outlet for the gap constraint, but is it possible in a simpler way, maybe from interface builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, this isn’t possible in XIB. I’ve filed enhancement requests (starting even before this shipped). File more! The more votes this gets, the more likely it is to happen.

We ended up adding an outlet onto our subclass of ImageView that we point at the constraint we want to go away, and in the subclass disabling the constraint when the image is nil (we use different tricks to disable it in different places, since there’s no one single easy way).

Comment: It's super easy to install and uninstall constraints nowadays, but I don't know of a way to totally automatically do the "image is nil so skip this constraint" thing yet.